# pip wheel created without any python sub-packages

Tags: python, django, pip, python-wheel

**operating system and version**

*Ubuntu 18.04 VM hosted by WIN10*

**Python version**

*Python 2.7.15rc1*

**version of pip**

*pip 18.0*

**description**

*I'm trying to package Django project and wheel created but without any python sub-packages

what i'm missing please ??
*

## Folder structure

zoharngo@zoharngo-VirtualBox:~/todobackend$ tree -L 4

.

├── manage.py

├── setup.py

```
└── todobackend

    ├── __init__.py
    ├── todo
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── serializers.py
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── views.py
    └── todobackend
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── settings
        │   ├── base.py
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   ├── release.py
        │   └── test.py
        ├── urls.py
        └── wsgi.py
```

### setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
name                 = "todobackend",
version              = "0.1.0",
description          = "TodoBackend Djnago REST service",
package              = find_packages(),
include_package_data = True,
scripts              = ["manage.py"],
install_requires     = ["Django>=1.9,<2.0",
                        "django-cors-headers>=2.4.0",
                        "djangorestframework>=3.8.2",
                        "MySQL-python>=1.2.5",
                        "uwsgi>=2.0"
                        ],
 extras_require     =   {
                            "test": [
                                "colorama>=0.3.9",
                                "coverage>=4.5.1",
                                "django-nose>=1.4.5",
                                "nose>=1.3.7",
                                "pinocchio>=0.4.2"
                            ]
                        }
```

)

Comment: If you're facing any issue in doing so, please specify the `traceback` with this.

Comment: @Zogar, please specify exactly how what you get with this setup is different from what you need.

Comment: no traceback the built completed without errors but packages were not included inside the wheel only info  5 directories, 20 files
`(venv) ~/todobackend/dist$ unzip -l todobackend-0.1.0-py2-none-any.whl
Archive:  todobackend-0.1.0-py2-none-any.whl
     todobackend-0.1.0.data/scripts/manage.py
     todobackend-0.1.0.dist-info/top_level.txt
     todobackend-0.1.0.dist-info/WHEEL
     todobackend-0.1.0.dist-info/METADATA
     todobackend-0.1.0.dist-info/RECORD`

Comment: no traceback the built completed without errors but packages were not included inside the wheel only todobackend-0.1.0.dist-info but not folder with packages python code ..

Comment: The correct keyword is `packages`, not `package`. `setup(packages=find_packages())`

Comment: @hoefling you saved me .. i so much appreciate it thanks u and others for your dedicated help !!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the only wheel will be your package, the others will be downloaded when setup.py is run. If you want to create an artefact that requires no downloading it is possible to do the following (this assumes a virtualenv in the folder `venv`):

```
venv/bin/pip download --dest wheels/ --no-cache-dir .
venv/bin/python setup.py sdist --dist-dir="wheels"
tar -czvf dist/artefact.tar.gz wheels/
```

You can reunpack this artefact into a venv without downloading anything using

```
tar -xzf artefact.tar.gz
virtualenv --no-download venv
venv/bin/pip install --force-reinstall --no-index --no-cache-dir --find-links=./wheels/ todobackend
```